# Predicting length of UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync tokens (via DataProtectorTokenProvider)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1, with some custom logic that reuses ASP.NET Core Identity's `UserManager<TUser>` class. I want to reuse its ability to `GenerateUserTokenAsync(...)`, the same type of token also used in e.g. e-mail confirmations. For my application's purpose, **I need to know the maximum length for generated tokens**.

I've done the following research:

- `UserManager<TUser>.GenerateUserTokenAsync(...)` [calls `GenerateAsync` on the injected provider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/83448b47a0960aeb87169192f20888884796a243/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1743-L1760)
- in my case that is the `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>` which will [generate tokens like this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/83448b47a0960aeb87169192f20888884796a243/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs#L75-L104):

  ```
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  var userId = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
  using (var writer = ms.CreateWriter())
  {
      writer.Write(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
      writer.Write(userId);
      writer.Write(purpose ?? "");
      string stamp = null;
      if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
      {
          stamp = await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
      }
      writer.Write(stamp ?? "");
  }
  var protectedBytes = Protector.Protect(ms.ToArray());
  return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedBytes);
  ```
- So the basic calculation for length of the memory stream would be:

  ```
  27 characters for DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
  36 characters for the user id (string representation of a GUID)
  20 characters for my specific "purpose" string
  36 characters for the security stamp (string representation of a GUID)
  ---- +
  119 characters in total
  ```
- In the code snippet this gets `Protect`ed and then converted `ToBase64String`

When I casually tested this on my local machine, I got an **encrypted string of 352 characters**. How could I predict that the 119 input characters would become 352 characters when encrypted? And worse, my app runs actually in production on an Azure App Service where Azure's [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) should kick in, possibly with different encryption than on localhost?

**Can I in any way predict what the maximum length of the generated User Tokens will be on Azure App Services?** I'm happy to include a margin of error, but am clueless what that would need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default DPAPI uses AES-256-CBC as encryption algorithm unless you change it via [UseCryptographicAlgorithms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#changing-algorithms-with-usecryptographicalgorithms). As per default algo, the calculation would go like this for your case:

Since it's AES 256, it would work with 32 bytes block. So with CBC padding, you output becomes ((119/32) + 1) * 32  + 16 (IV) = 144. After base64, it becomes 192.

So, having it 352 brings up the question is the stamp really 36 in your case?

> 36 characters for the security stamp (string representation of a GUID)

Also, in deployed environment, make sure to [store data protection key outside app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) since each instance of the app service needs to point to the same key.